Angular 17 SSR - Page Data Not Refreshing / Updating
I have list page , which is a list of the latest posts.  When I add a new one to the datastore, the new one is not shown in the page.
ngOnInit() {
 
    if(isPlatformServer(this.platformID)){ //<--- this block run on server
       this.apiCall()
      }
      else if(isPlatformBrowser(this.platformID)){
        this.apiCall()
        this.bindingData=this.transferState.get<{data:string}>(dataKey,{data:""});
        this.articles = JSON.parse(this.bindingData.data);
  
      }
 
}

